# Accessing database in form

Tags: java

Struggling with a project I'm building. I'm new to Java and this is just something I'm putting together for practice. This is a form that is part of, sort of a cash register. You are to select an item and add it to the card. My issue is in the `getById()` method, on line: `for ( Inventory candidateItem : inventoryDao.findAll())`. Specifically the `inventoryDao.findAll()`. That is a call to a database I created and it works in my controllers but it doesn't work here. I feel like may be to do with that "static" because I can remove that but it breaks other things.

```
public class Cart {

@Autowired
    private InventoryDao inventoryDao;

    static ArrayList<Inventory> cart = new ArrayList<>();


    public static ArrayList<Inventory> getAll() {
        return cart;
    }



    public static void add(int id) {
        Inventory cartItemToAdd = getById(id);
        cart.add(cartItemToAdd);
    }

    public static void remove(int id) {
        Inventory cartItemToRemove = getById(id);
        cart.remove(cartItemToRemove);
    }

    //Issue is here.....
    public static Inventory getById(int id) {

        Inventory theItem = null;
        // InventoryDao inventoryDao = null;
        for ( Inventory candidateItem : inventoryDao.findAll()) {  //<---here
            if (candidateItem.getId() == id) {
                theItem = candidateItem;
            }
        }
        return theItem;
    }

    public static void clearCart() { //this shoud effective reset teh array list. Used when sending the completed order to DB or just clearing car
        ArrayList<Inventory> cart = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

Comment: please add your stack trace error too

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work here"? What happens? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: By not working I mean it isn't recognized. On my controller the command works on my controllers with the only error recommending me to add an import statement. But in this model it isn't recognized, even if I add that import statement.